# Parent Div(s) min height of first child with class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with basic markup as:-

```
<div class="jp-container" style="height: 400px;">
<div class="jspContainer" style="height: 400px;">
<div class="class="jspPane">
  <div class="cfg-item"></div>
  <div class="cfg-item"></div>
  <div class="cfg-item"></div>
  <div class="cfg-item"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

problem with the feed is that the height of the paren(s) is fixed to 400px (or another arbitrary figure). So my question is:-

How can I ensure that the parent container divs min-heights are set to the first div with class "cfg-item". Idea is to show the full output of the first Facebook feed item so none is cut off.

I have something like:-

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.jspContainer .cff-item').first(function(){
$('.jspContainer, .jp-container').css('min-height', $(this).outerHeight());
}); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe didn't understand well your question, but if you want to select the first div with the class `.cfg-item` try this path:

```
$(".jspPane").next(".cfg-item");
```

SO you call the "container" div of all the `.cfg-item` divs and you select the first one.

Hope it helped, as soon as I understand better or you explain a little better I try to give you something more precise.

**EDIT1:**

To be more specific you can do this:

```
 $("div.jspPane").next("div.cfg-item");
```

**EDIT2:**

HTML:

`<div class="jp-container minHeight" style="height: 400px;">
<div class="jspContainer minHeight" style="height: 400px;">`

jQuery:

```
// We declare variables
var containers = $(".minHeight");   //We put both containers in same variable with same class
var firstChild = $(".jspPane").next(".cfg-item").height();  //We get the first child height

containers.css('min-height', firstChild);  //We give the containers the height of the first child
```

I didn't check this, I am at work and don't have much time. I can check it later.

I hope it helped you, and at least gave you some ideas. Good luck! ;)

Comment: To confirm I would like the containers with classes' .jp-container' and '.jp-container' to have a minimum height of the first child div '.cfg-item'

Comment: @user2463284 Edited my answer, let's see if this helps you a little bit. I don't have much time. Hope it works fine for you! ;)

Comment: Hi I'm afraid that didn't work for me. As this is a component I can't add the class 'minHeight' but I tried it on one of the container classes that should have the same effect. No joy I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh, Ok. If I manage to have some spare time today I try research a bit for you. ;)